# Spectral norm of a difference matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, image-processing

Let $M,N\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ and suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}^{M N}$. Denote $x$ by
\begin{align}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
\vdots \\
x_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^M$ for each $i$. Define a matrix $L\in\mathbb{R}^{M(N-1)+(M-1)N \times MN}$ such that
\begin{align}
Lx = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}-x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{N-1} - x_{N} \\
A x_1 \\
\vdots \\
A x_N \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M-1\times M}$ is
\begin{align}
A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & -1
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
What is the spectral norm $||L||_{2}$, or alternatively, find an upper bound better than the Frobenius norm $||L||_{F}$.

Comment: Found $||L||_{2}^{2}\leq8$ and it worked well for my application.